# Initial condition of pydrake simulation not what I expect

Tags: drake, meshcat

I'm running into an issue with simulation in pydrake where I'm trying to initialize my robot at a certain configuration, and what I see at t = 0 in meshcat is close to, but not quite that.

I'm solving an inverse kinematics problem to initialize my robot on a ladder. I expect it to look like this (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images):

[Correct behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNWWz.png)

Instead, it looks like this:

[Incorrect behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBhpY.png)

It's most visible in the end-effectors (see purple arrows). This will be a problem when I re-enable collision, it looks like the simulation wills tart in collision.

I think the problem is related to how I'm connecting up the controller:

```
# connect up the controller
    controller = builder.AddSystem(BasicController(plant))
    builder.Connect(controller.GetOutputPort("torques"),
                    plant.get_actuation_input_port(parcli))
    builder.Connect(plant.get_state_output_port(),
                    controller.GetInputPort("state"))
```

If I run with the above, I get the undesired behavior. When I comment out the first `builder.Connect()` line, it behaves correctly. Also, when I leave that line uncommented, but inside the controller, I just set it to always output zero torque, I also get the right behavior.

I kind of feel like meshcat/visualizer is considering t = 0 to be a time that's already several timesteps in. I'm doing the usual thing for simulation/visualization:

```
# Run the simulation 
    meshcat.StartRecording()
    finish_time = 1
    simulator.AdvanceTo(finish_time)
    meshcat.PublishRecording()
```

Comment: If you are looking at the visualization at time zero of the recording, then please make sure that you are using the most up-to-date Drake. We did have a bug (fixed in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/20926) where the default recording framerate set by MeshcatVisualizer led to having a frame published at frame 0.5 overwriting the one published at zero.

Comment: @RussTedrake thanks for the quick reply - I was on python drake version 1.25, and just `pip install --upgrade`d to 1.26, which was released last month, but the problem persists. do i need to be on a nightly for this fix?

Comment: The fix in that PR simply sets the default frames_per_second to be less problematic. If you simple pass `frames_per_second=64` as an argument into `StartRecording`, that should do the trick.

Comment: @RussTedrake, thanks for the reply - I tried setting `frames_per_second=64` and to `100`, but the problem persists.

Another clue is that it behaves correctly when i initialize the robot well away from the ladder. However, it does the incorrect behavior when i initialize it "on" the ladder but turn off ladder collision geometry (by commenting the `<collision>` in the SDF). In my mind there should be no difference between the two...

Comment: Update: I am a silly goose, I've been initializing off the ladder it in the `q_desired` configuration off the ladder, resulting in zero torques at `t = 0`, which is why initializing "well away from the ladder" worked the way it did. Will do some more digging.